# Chaining Bash command with double ampersand - unexpected behavior

Tags: bash, chaining, ampersand

The following works well

```sh
> killall httpd

> service httpd start
Starting httpd:                 [  OK  ]

> service httpd status
httpd (pid  2987) is running...
```

The following is supposed to work like above, but it's not

```sh
> killall httpd && service httpd start
Starting httpd:

> service httpd status
httpd is stopped
```

Note that here it didn't return the `[OK]` signal for starting httpd.

What is going wrong? Do Bash commands by ampersand chaining run asynchronously? How can I make sure that they run synchronously one **after** another?

Comment: What about using the `-w, --wait` argument of `killall`?: `killall -w httpd && service httpd start`

Comment: What about `service httpd stop`?

Comment: Or better yet, `service httpd restart`?

Comment: Bash waits for `killall` to finish sending signals and exit before starting `service httpd start`, but that's not the same as waiting for the signaled httpd processes to finish cleaning up and exiting in response to those signals.

Comment: @higuaro - your suggestion actually worked... the `--wait` switch on `killall` was needed to ensure that the second part is executed ONLY AFTER the killall had actually completed killing off all httpd... why don't you propose this as an answer and i shall accept it as the right answer for this question

Comment: @syedrakib, I'd suggest that other guy's answer -- which also solves the problem, but in a more generalized way than using `killall` (since letting the individual program's service scripts decide how best to kill it ensures that any program is shut down in the way it's designed to be, whereas `killall` can end up signaling subprocesses/helper processes out-of-order; it's a very brute-force tool).

Comment: @CharlesDuffy you explained the matter correctly. However, my question was about the double ampersand behaving unexpectedly, not about what's the right way to achieve what i am trying to achieve. May be you can write an answer with the `--wait` switch to answer the question... and then include in your answer why `service restart` is the better way than even with the `--wait` switch ;-)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is that signalling (with `killall`) is asynchronous.

In your non-interactive case, the server is still running when you ask it to start, because it hasn't had time to exit.

In your interactive case, the second long delay before you issue the next command is enough to allow the process to shut down. Starting it again therefore works.

The proper solution is `service httpd restart`, which both kills and starts the server.

Comment: killall with the `--wait` switched worked for me... `killall httpd --wait && service httpd start`. That should be good right?

Comment: Yes. It makes `killall` repeatedly poll the process until it exits. Once it has exited, it can be successfully started.

Comment: so now the debate is `killall httpd --wait && service httpd start` vs. `service httpd restart`. Which is supposed to be better and why?

Comment: `service httpd restart` is better because it specifically stops and restarts the system's `httpd` service in the manner it prefers. `killall` is a heavy handed and kills a bunch of processes, hopefully including the ones you want.

Answer (score 1):

In this case I think you should use a semicolon instead of the double ampersand.
I don't think the killall command always signals appropriately for what you're trying to do.
Certainly if there are no running httpd tasks it will fail.

Comment: That doesn't fix the problem -- there's still no guarantee that the signaled httpd processes will finish exiting before the `start` is run.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy is right... it doesn't guarantee that httpd is killed first... the answer to this is the --wait option on killall command. `killall httpd --wait && service httpd start`

Answer (score 1):

The `--wait` switch was important in this situation (*however, the better solution is stated later.*)

```
killall httpd --wait && service httpd start
```

This ensured that killall completed killing all httpd services and ***ONLY THEN*** proceed to starting a new httpd service.

However, I also learned that, simply doing **`service httpd restart`** would be the better thing to do in this scenario than killing all httpd and starting a new httpd.

Comment: "completed killing" is perhaps ambiguous. To suggest some more precise wording: Without `--wait`, killall completed _sending TERM signals to_ the other processes and exited before `service httpd start` is run; however, it did not wait for those processes to *respond* to the signals, so `service httpd start` could be run after the TERM signals were received, but before the old httpd instances had completed shutting down in response to them; `killall --wait` checks to see that the things it signalled exited before it exits itself.